# Android: is it possible to paint a large image without resampling?

Tags: android

I would like to read images from InputStreams, and draw them to my canvas.  Unfortunately, the images may be very large, and could easily cause out of memory exceptions.  BitmapFactory allows me to provide a sample size value, which will down sample the image as it is processed and avoid the memory issues.  However, image quality suffers.

Ideally, canvas would provide a paint image method which can paint from an InputStream, as opposed to from a Bitmap, but I haven't found anything of this type.  Does this exist, or is there any other way to safely render arbitrarily large images from InputStreams without down sampling?

Comment: I'm very much afraid you have to create a Bitmap unless you take the 'drawPixel' approach and implement your own InputStream drawing method.

Comment: I did this for png images, where I decode the image one line of pixels at a time, drawing as I go.  Unfortunately, I need to use the BitmapFactory for jpeg images, because I don't know how to decode Jpegs, which is where my problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be: no, there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what image format you are using but if you want to send a lossless image (or with less loss than has already occurred), It can't be compressed better than JPEG. so, use JPEG first.

Here is an example for drawing image on Canvas. Override the 'draw' method. http://www.androidsnippets.com/drawing-an-image-as-a-map-overlay2

At the end, hacking it

Probably, pre-splitting the image; compressing each individual one and restoring at the end sounds logical.

Here are few attempts,

http://kalanir.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-split-image-into-chunks-java.html

And

http://www.anddev.org/multimedia-problems-f28/chunk-of-a-big-big-image-t6211.html

Comment: Thank you for your response.  However, this is not a usable solution for my situation.